# SQL - ordering does not work with LENGTH function

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle-apex

I'm trying to sort out my query based on `V.SITES_CODE`. It works without the `LENGTH` function, but with the function the order is completely random. Can someone help here is the code:

```
SELECT     V.CODE_OF_HOLIDAY, V.SITES_CODE, A.SITES_NAME, D.DESCRIPTION
FROM       ZZZ_SITES_VISITED V, ZZZ_SITES_AVAILABLE A, ZZZ_HOLIDAY_DETAILS H, ZZZ_DIFFICULTY_RATINGS D
WHERE      V.CODE_OF_HOLIDAY = H.CODE_OF_HOLIDAY
AND        A.SITES_CODE = V.SITES_CODE(+)
AND        H.DIFFICULTY_RATING = D.HOLIDAY_DIFICULTY
AND        H.CODE_OF_HOLIDAY = V.CODE_OF_HOLIDAY
AND        LENGTH(D.DESCRIPTION) > 6;
```

Comment: You have no `order by` clause.  In addition, you should learn to use modern `join` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you explicitly specify an `order by` clause, there is absolutely no guarantee on the order of rows returned. The fact that you got them in the order you expected when you omitted to `length` condition is completely coincidental, and may very well break if the table is moved to different storage or the indexes rebuilt.

If you want your result ordered by `V.SITES_CODE`, you should explicitly state it:

```
SELECT     V.CODE_OF_HOLIDAY, V.SITES_CODE, A.SITES_NAME, D.DESCRIPTION
FROM       ZZZ_SITES_VISITED V, ZZZ_SITES_AVAILABLE A, ZZZ_HOLIDAY_DETAILS H, ZZZ_DIFFICULTY_RATINGS D
WHERE      V.CODE_OF_HOLIDAY = H.CODE_OF_HOLIDAY
AND        A.SITES_CODE = V.SITES_CODE(+)
AND        H.DIFFICULTY_RATING = D.HOLIDAY_DIFICULTY
AND        H.CODE_OF_HOLIDAY = V.CODE_OF_HOLIDAY
AND        LENGTH(D.DESCRIPTION) > 6
ORDER BY   V.SITES_CODE
```

Answer (score 1):

`Oracle` does not have any default `sorting`. you **MUST** explicitly specify `ORDER BY` clause to reply on the sorting.

Add,

```
ORDER BY V.SITES_CODE
```

Comment: Outside of MySQL, any proper RDBMS requires explicit ORDER BY in the outermost select